# Trouble understanding the difference between passing result to another function and retuning result to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping, return

I've written a script in python using two functions within it. The first function is supposed to get some links from a webpage and the other should print it in the console.

My question is what difference does it make when I pass the result from one function to another function using `return` keyword like `return get_info(elem)`? Usually doing only this `get_info(elem)`, I can pass stuffs from one function to another then when to choose this `return get_info(elem)` and why?

An example might be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    elem = soup.select_one(".info h2 a[data-analytics]").get("href")
    get_info(elem)  #why this one
    return get_info(elem) #or why this

def get_info(link):
    print(link)
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be thinking of languages like Ruby which has implicit returns. Python doesn't have those and neither do most languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first simplify your function so that you can run it and compare the results:

```
def get_links(url):
    url = "this returns link: {}".format(url)
    get_info(url)  #why this one
    return get_info(url) #or why this

def get_info(link):
    print(link)

get_links('google.com')
>>this returns link: google.com
>>this returns link: google.com
```

Your function now returns `print` twice. First when you called the function, and second when you returned the function, and in this case actually returns `None` because `get_info` does not return anything.

This is evident here:

```
url = get_links('google.com')
>>this returns link: google.com
>>this returns link: google.com

url
>> *nothing happens*
```

The results of return are more apparent if it actually does something, for example:

```
def get_links(url):
    url = "this returns link: {}".format(url)
    return get_info(url)

def get_info(link):
    return "get_info does something, {}".format(link)

url = get_links('google.com')
url

>>'get_info does something, this returns link: google.com'
```

If you do not use return, it just means the function will not return anything, which happens for example if you just want to `print` the results as you did. You can further try this out by assigning a name like I did above to a function does has no return and the result will essentially be `None`.

Comment: I don't think he's calling the function twice. He's just asking what the difference is between calling it with or without `return`.

Comment: I just meant to illustrate that the 2 calls in `get_links` call `get_info` twice, one with `return` and one without does not return any value even when assigned to a variable because it is probably different than the way he intended it to work.

Comment: Read the comments in the code, it says "why this ... or this". He wants to know why he should use one or the other.

Comment: Perhaps. Why was too broad for me to answer and therefore I replied with an explanation of what it does.

Comment: If you haven't come across ***[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434370/how-to-handle-invalidschema-exception)*** already, please take a look @BernardL.

Comment: Lol ok @robots.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
return get_info(elem)
```

will call the `get_info()` function, then take whatever it returned, and return that same value from `get_links()`. It's roughly equivalent to:

```
temp = get_info(elem)
return temp
```

But since `get_info()` doesn't return anything, it just prints the link, there's not much point in using it in a `return` statement. Writing just

```
get_info(elem)
```

calls the function without doing anything with its return value (if it returned anything).

Comment: I can see a huge difference between them when I go through this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416806/script-throws-an-error-when-it-is-made-to-run-using-multiprocessing). The script in the answer has got this `return get_data(itemlink['href'])` without which I don't get any result. I meant I don't get any result when I do `get_data(itemlink['href'])`.

Comment: `get_data` doesn't return anything, it just prints, like the `get_info` function here.