# How to handle InvalidSchema exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping, return

I've written a script in python using two functions within it. The first function `get_links()` fetches some links from a webpage and returns those links to another function `get_info()`. At this point the function `get_info()` should produce the different shop names from different links but It throws an error `raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)`.

This is my try:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    elem = soup.select(".info h2 a[data-analytics]")
    return get_info(elem)

def get_info(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    return soup.select_one("#main-header .sales-info h1").get_text(strip=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=%20Injury%20Law%20Attorneys&geo_location_terms=California&page=2'    
    for review in get_links(link):
        print(urljoin(link,review.get("href")))
```

***The key thing that I'm trying to learn here is the real-life usage of `return get_info(elem)`***

I created another thread concerning this `return get_info(elem)`. [Link to that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424187/trouble-understanding-the-difference-between-passing-result-to-another-function).

***When I try like the following, I get the results accordingly***:

```
def get_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    elem = soup.select(".info h2 a[data-analytics]")
    return elem

def get_info(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    return soup.select_one("#main-header .sales-info h1").get_text(strip=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=%20Injury%20Law%20Attorneys&geo_location_terms=California&page=2'    
    for review in get_links(link):
        print(get_info(urljoin(link,review.get("href"))))
```

***My question: how can I get the results according to the way I tried with my first script making use of `return get_info(elem)`?***

Comment: Please take a 2nd look at the title of your question. It's 100% non-descriptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect what is returned by each function. In this case, the function in your first script will never run. The reason because `get_info` takes in a URL, not anything else. So obviously you are going to hit an error when you run `get_info(elem)` where `elem` is a list of items that are selected by `soup.select()`.

You should already know the above though because you are iterating over the results from the second script which just returns the list to get the `href` elements. So if you want to use `get_info` in your first script, apply it on the items not the list, you can use a list comprehension in this case.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    elem = soup.select(".info h2 a[data-analytics]")
    return [get_info(urljoin(link,e.get("href"))) for e in elem] 

def get_info(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    return soup.select_one("#main-header .sales-info h1").get_text(strip=True)

link = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=%20Injury%20Law%20Attorneys&geo_location_terms=California&page=2'

for review in get_links(link): 
    print(review)
```

Now you know the first function still returns a list, but with `get_info` applied to its elements, which is how it works rite? `get_info` accepts a URL not a list. From there since you have already applied the `url_join` and `get_info` in `get_links`, you can loop it over to print the results.

Comment: Hope it helped, be patient and take your time to understand the basic data types and how it works using Python, it will give you a stronger foundation in better design in the future. Cheers.